# I try to find a simple way in Java 8 stream API to do the grouping

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I try to find a simple way in Java 8 stream API to do the grouping.

```
Path caminho = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "log.txt");



    Files.lines(caminho, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
            .map(linha -> {
                return  getUrl(linha);
            })
            .filter(url -> url != null)
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Arquivo::getUrl,
                            LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting() ),

                    Collectors.groupingBy(Arquivo::getStatusCode,
                            LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

it is possible?

Comment: You can't do two simultaneous groupings without rolling the combination yourself. I'd probably just accept streaming the file twice.

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t describe your use case, so one possible answer is that you can just group both properties into a single map, assuming that these properties have no overlapping value, which would be always the case, if they have different type:

```
Path caminho = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "log.txt");
LinkedHashMap<Object, Long> map = Files.lines(caminho, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
    .map(linha -> getUrl(linha))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .flatMap(arquivo -> Stream.of(arquivo.getUrl(), arquivo.getStatusCode()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                   LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting() ));
```

for the resulting map, lookup of either key would succeed and also iterating over it would yield to the right order, you’ll only have to skip the keys of the type you’re not interested in.

If both properties have the same type, say e.g. `String`, and could have overlapping values, including a marker would help:

```
Map<Boolean, LinkedHashMap<String, Long>> map
 = Files.lines(caminho, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
        .map(linha -> getUrl(linha))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(arquivo -> Stream.of(Arrays.asList(arquivo.getUrl(), true),
                                      Arrays.asList(arquivo.getStatusCode(), false)))
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(l -> (Boolean)l.get(1),
                    Collectors.groupingBy(l -> (String)l.get(0),
                                          LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting() )));
LinkedHashMap<String, Long> urls   = map.get(true);
LinkedHashMap<String, Long> status = map.get(false);
```

This does not only solve the overlapping, but also provides you with two distinct maps, but unfortunately, it doesn’t work so smoothly, if the two properties have different types.